# Turning a CSV file into a dictionary

Tags: python

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m5fZ.png)

I am trying to make a dictionary using the values in the table above. I am trying to use 'Genre' as the Key and then a list of tuples for the name, publisher, and platform. [variable explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WI7t.png)

`D1[genre] = { genre: [(name, publisher, platform),..],..}`

My Code:

```
import csv
fp = open('video_game_sales_tiny.csv','r')

fp.readline()
data_reader = csv.reader(fp)
D1 = {}


 for line in data_reader:

    name = line[0].lower()
    platform = line[1]
    year = line[2]
    genre = line[3].lower()
    publisher = line[4].lower()

    D1[genre] = [name, publisher, platform, year]
```

There are multiple Genres with the same name, and when the loop gets to a genre that matches the Key, it copies over dictionary instead of adding a tuple to the dictionary.

I am trying to make the dictionary look like:

`D1 = { Puzzle: [ (Pac-man, Atari, 2600, 1982),(BurgerTime, Mattel Interactive, 2600, 1981), (Q*bert, Parker Bros, 2600, 1982), Shooter: [ (),(), ()], Action: [ (),(), ()] }`

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the sample csv file _as text_ so other can use if for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the values of your dictionary an array of tuples. Then you can append new tuples instead of overwriting them. Here is an example using your code:

```
for line in data_reader:
  name = line[0].lower()
  platform = line[1]
  year = line[2]
  genre = line[3].lower()
  publisher = line[4].lower()
  if genre in D1:
    D1[genre].append((name, publisher, platform, year))
  else:
    D1[genre] = [(name, publisher, platform, year)]
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept my answer and vote up if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in data_reader:
  name = line[0].lower()
  platform = line[1]
  year = line[2]
  genre = line[3].lower()
  publisher = line[4].lower()
  if genre in D1:
    D1[genre].append((name, publisher, platform, year))
  else:
    D1[genre] = [(name, publisher, platform, year)]
```